# Storing Objects in ArrayList, Can Use only Last one stored

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, file-io

i Have a file that has for input something like this:`SNACK NAME PRICE`, spaced by a Tab.
Using this code that i wrote, i store everything in an ArrayList of Obj Products:

```
public ArrayList<Product> listsnack = new ArrayList<>();
       public Product readSnack() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                snackline = linea.split("\t");
                String code =snackline[0];
                String name = snackline[1];
                String price = snackline[2];
                Product p1 = new Product(snackline[0], snackline[1], snackline[2]);
                listsnack.add(p1);

            }
 Product p1 = new Product(snackline[0], snackline[1], snackline[2]);
            return p1;
        }
```

And, while printing using a for  cycle,  it produces this Output(that i think it's correct):

```
Product{code=PATA1, name=rustica san carlo, price=0.4}
Product{code=PATA2, name=chipsters, price=0.35}
Product{code=KIND1, name=ovetto kinder, price=0.75}
```

Now, i want to write a method which, by using Keyboard input that matches the Product code and the correct prices, it displays "Supply has being done correctly".

I'm trying to call a new:

```
Readfile f= new Readfile();
f.readSnack().code \\ Comparing this to System.in input
```

But when i use this in my method it just works for the last element in the ArrayList.
What am i doing wrong?
Best regards

Comment: Well, by the looks of it your `readSnack` method only returns the last snack (`p1` after the loop). Perhaps you meant to return the `List`?

Comment: @Zircon not even that, it created another new `Product` with the same information as the last `Product`, but this `Product` is actually a completly different instance as the last `Produkt` in the `listsnack` `List`.

Comment: @KevinEsche Got it, so how can i make a return to the entire List and not only to the last element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to build your function like this. After you call it you can loop though the products and print them all.

```
public List<Product> readSnacks() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    List<Product> listsnack = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        snackline = linea.split("\t");
        String code =snackline[0];
        String name = snackline[1];
        String price = snackline[2];
        Product p1 = new Product(snackline[0], snackline[1], snackline[2]);
        listsnack.add(p1);
    }
    return listsnack;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
List<Product> snacks = readSnacks();
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot!
Now i'm writing the method to  supply snacks but when i istance a new object i can only write " readfile.listsnack.get(i).*whatineeed* " but i need all items, not just one.
For example, for Every item i need the Price section... should i do a for-each loop?

Comment: yeah - foreach loop